# Adding a new entry to an XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, append, simplexml

I hate to keep asking for help, but I'm tripping over myself with this. The last thing I need to do is to add a new entry to my xml file. The xml structure is this:

```
<employees>
    <employee EmpID="">
        <first_name></first_name>
        <last_name></last_name>
        <ssnum></ssnum>
        <status></status>
        <contact_info>
                <office_phone></office_phone>
                <email></email>
                <cell_phone></cell_phone>
        </contact_info>
        <access_info level="user">
                <username></username>
                <password></password>
        </access_info>
        <department></department>
        <date_started></date_started>
        <years></years>
        <position></position>
        <salary></salary>
        <e_increase></e_increase>
        <e_raise></e_raise>
        <photo></photo>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

I want to add a new employee, with all the appropriate information. All of the values are stored in variables already. I've looked into things like:

```
$employees= new SimpleXMLElement;

$employees->loadfile("xml/employee.xml");

$employees->addChild("employee");

$employees->save('xml/employee.xml');
```

But I'm not sure how to add attributes, and set the right child elements etc. Could someone provide me with an example? Everything I've found on here either doesn't deal with attributes or doesn't have children of child elements.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at the examples in the documentation.. http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php

Comment: I've been there but I'm having trouble making heads or tails of the examples. I don't understand what goes where for what...

Comment: Just see ***Example #1 Add attributes and children to a SimpleXML element*** on the page @Kevin linked. It's all in there. And it goes there for that :) - Try what they outline there and if it still does not work show how far you've come by updating your question here.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML is great for traversing/reading an XML document, but if you want to add elements, including attributes, etc, you're better off to go with a full functioning library, like [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php)

(You *can* add elements (as you describe in your example), but it's not 100% fully functional like a normal XML Parser - hence the 'Simple').

Comment: Most of my application use DOM. I have found no information on DOMs for this though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with `sinplexml`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x

$newemp = $xml->addChild('employee',''); // add <employee>
$newemp->addAttribute('EmpID','9'); // add attribute

$contact = $newemp->addChild('contact_info',''); // add <contact_info> as child of <employee>
$contact->addChild('office_phone','');
```